# Draw bike route on google map

Tags: android, google-maps, dictionary, android-maps

I want to draw a bike route on google map for android. I study documentation by google on this site http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/directions/#Restrictions

1) I like to know how to get response from direction api and pass the response in map view to draw a route in the map (Sample code to draw the route).

2) In the documentation they given Waypoints to plot the route in continuous manner. how can i use it

3) How to Draw Elevation for a particular lat and log pts.

I search lots of websites for sample code in most of the websites they given it for KML to plot the routes.I study in one website KML is used to draw route for two points and i want to draw for multiple pts to get bike routes.

Any suggestion or sample code which help me...

Thanks in advance.